# Adding ecommerce functionalities to existing website

Tags: e-commerce

I've been asked to add ecommerce functionalities to a website with a non-ecommerce [template](https://www.astemplates.com/joomla-template-details/400-at-real-estate).

The website is quite simple, with like 20 products and just 5 pages, without complex functionalities. 
I haven't much time to complete the task, so I thought that create a new website with another template or use something more ecommerce oriented like Prestahop should be faster than modifying the actual template, adding all the ecommerce functionalities.

Am I right? There are painless solutions for such a task?

Consider that Joomla isn't my field ( I use mostly Wordpress, Craft, Prestahop ) and the website is using some sort of page builder.

Comment: Adding e-commerce functionality is not something that is done within the template. Template is for the look and feel. - If you are right? I don't think so... Why to create a second site for extending the functionality of the current one? Certainly the fact that you are not familiar with a technology is not a good reason for this. What will happen if as a next task they ask you to add forum, or community features? Will you creating new websites each time? IMHO, If you feel not capable to offer what they asked you, it's better to kindly reject the task.

Answer (score 1):

The best long term solution is probably to learn the existing CMS and extend it to include e-commerce using [an appropriate e-commerce extension](https://extensions.joomla.org/category/e-commerce). This will minimise ongoing maintenance.

Most templates should work fine with any e-commerce solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding e-commerce functionality is not something that is done within the template. Template is for the look and feel.

If you are right? I don't think so... Why to create a second site for extending the functionality of the current one? Certainly the fact that you are not familiar with a technology is not a good reason for this. What will happen if as a next task they ask you to add forum, or community features? Will you creating new websites each time?

IMHO, If you feel not capable to offer what they asked you, it's better to kindly reject the task.

Comment: I see the approach of multiple platforms for each purpose on various websites though, ex shop.something.com with Prestashop, blog.something.com with Wordpress, forum-something.com with PhpBB etc.
Is that so bad in your opinion?

Comment: @AlessioBreviglieri - This discussion has started on a wrong base. However, I don't say that the above setup is bad or good. Going that route is not just a matter of opinion. Projects should be defined by their requirements and have a scope. I was also clear why I said what I said.  The lack of knowledge by someone should not be the reason to force changing the technology/platform of an established project, or to extend it by using something that this someone is familiar with. That's a bad and unprofessional practice in my opinion.